# Passing generic parameter results in wrong overload being called

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to update [Medusa](https://github.com/yojimbo87/Medusa) to allow decorated POCOs to be used anywhere it currently uses `List<DbParameter>`. The problem I'm running into is that the wrong overload is being called. Here is a simple example of what I'm seeing:

```
void Run()
{
    CallDoSomething<Program>("Hello World", new object());
    CallDoSomething<Program>("Hello World2", new List<int>());
}

// `DoSomething<T>` represents the functions that do the heavy lifting
public T DoSomething<T>(string someString, List<int> ints) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine("List<int>: {0}", someString);
    return default(T);
}
public T DoSomething<T>(string someString, object ints) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine("object: {0}", someString);
    // In my real implementation, this turns the object to a typed List<T>
    // and passes it to the previous overload.
    return default(T);
}

// We're trying to refactor the code in this method to reduce code duplication in
// the `CallDoSomething<T>` methods that will actually be called by the end user
internal T CallDoSomething<T, U>(string someString, U ints) where T : class
{
    // Do a bunch of stuff here that would otherwise be duplicated by the `CallDoSomething<T>` methods
    return DoSomething<T>(someString, ints);
}

public T CallDoSomething<T>(string someString, List<int> ints) where T : class
{
    return CallDoSomething<T, List<int>>(someString, ints);
}
public T CallDoSomething<T>(string someString, object ints) where T : class
{
    return CallDoSomething<T, object>(someString, ints);
}
```

In this case, the resulting output is:

```
object: Hello World
object: Hello World2
```

While I was expecting it to be:

```
object: Hello World
List<int>: HelloWorld2
```

It kind of makes sense that both cases were directed to the overload taking an `object` parameter since both of them are objects. I suspect this is happening because (from what I know) Generics and overload resolution are handled at compile time rather than runtime.

The first alternative that came to me was to use Reflection to invoke the call dynamically in `CallDoSomething<T, U>`, but that felt too dirty. Instead the solution I've come up with involves passing a delegate to `CallDoSomething<T, U>` which seems to work. Here's what it looks like:

```
void Run()
{
    CallDoSomething<Program>("Hello World", new object());
    CallDoSomething<Program>("Hello World2", new List<int>());
}

public T DoSomething<T>(string someString, List<int> ints) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine("List<int>: {0}", someString);
    return default(T);
}
public T DoSomething<T>(string someString, object ints) where T : class
{
    Console.WriteLine("object: {0}", someString);
    return default(T);
}

internal delegate T DoSomethingDelegate<T, U>(string someString, U ints) where T : class;
internal T CallDoSomething<T, U>(string someString, U ints, DoSomethingDelegate<T, U> doSomething) where T : class
{
    // Do a bunch of stuff here that would otherwise be duplicated by the `CallDoSomething<T>` methods
    return doSomething(someString, ints);
}

public T CallDoSomething<T>(string someString, List<int> ints) where T : class
{
    return CallDoSomething<T, List<int>>(someString, ints, DoSomething<T>);
}
public T CallDoSomething<T>(string someString, object ints) where T : class
{
    return CallDoSomething<T, object>(someString, ints, DoSomething<T>);
}
```

This seems to work and it removes a large amount of code duplication, but it makes the code fairly convoluted. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the overload is resolved at compile-time. You *can* force it to be evaluated at execution time if you're using C# 4, like this:

```
internal T CallDoSomething<T, U>(string someString, U ints) where T : class
{
    dynamic d = ints;
    return DoSomething<T>(someString, d);
}
```

However, personally I'd try to simplify your design if you possibly can. This sort of thing gets messy *very* quickly.

Comment: I am in .NET 4, so `dynamic` crossed my mind but I didn't think it would make much difference since `ints` is already a generic. It makes sense though. Any advice to simplify the design?

Comment: @M.Babcock: generic and dynamic are *very* different. Generics are about providing more type information at *compile time*; dynamic is about using more type information at *execution time*. As for simplifying the design - it's hard to say without knowing more context.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll probably stick with the delegates just to allow usage outside of .NET 4. While the delegate solution seems to work, do you know of any reason *not* to go this way?

Comment: @M.Babcock: Only simplicity. It feels like there should probably be a simpler approach...