# Generics and calling overloaded method from difference class - precedence issue

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

First of all, sorry for the title, but I couldn't think about anything better ...

My problem can be presented by simple code sample:

```cs
public static class Test<T>
{
    public static int GetInt(T source)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(source);
    }
}

public static class Convert
{
    public static int ToInt32(byte source)
    {
        return 30;
    }

    public static int ToInt32(object source)
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

**Why does `Console.WriteLine(Test<byte>.GetInt(20));` prints `10`, instead of `30`?**

I always thought that generics in .NET are resolved by JIT during runtime. Why then jitter isn't smart enough, to find out that there is `ToInt32(byte)` method, which suits our `byte` parameter type here?

This behavior makes `Convert` static class methods call result in boxing/unboxing operations for simple types.

Comment: `Test<byte>.GetInt(byte.Parse("20"))` returns 10 as well which I find stranger, The watch window says the type is object{byte} which might give some clue as to what is going on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has to decide at compile time which method to choose. It doesn't emit any code to decide at runtime which of the two overloads to pick. Because you haven't provided any evidence to the C# compiler that `GetInt(T source)` only works with `byte` structures, the compiler has to pick the other overload.

Or let me put it in a different perspective: if you remove the `ToInt32(object)` overload, your program fails to compile.

Comment: Is there any way to make it call the `byte` method (or in general, the best method available)?

Comment: check for typeof(T) == typeof(byte) +  cast to byte if true is the only way

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Is the boxing really a problem?

Comment: @Steven Yes, because there it gives unnecessary performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

> Compiler decides at compile time which method to execute.

I see through **Reflector** for **IL code** and found this -

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 GetInt(!T source) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: box !T
    L_0007: call int32 ConsoleApplication1.Convert::ToInt32(object) <-- HERE
    L_000c: stloc.0 
    L_000d: br.s L_000f
    L_000f: ldloc.0 
    L_0010: ret 
}
```

As mentioned by **Jon Skeet** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9279206/632337), you can make a call to byte method using `dynamic` which provides typed information at execution time instead of compile time.

```
public static class Test<T>
{
    public static int GetInt(T source)
    {
        dynamic dynamicSource = source;
        return Convert.ToInt32(dynamicSource );
    }
}
```